# Combine each element in a list of strings with another string

Tags: python

my input is:

```
list1=['car','bike','mango']
```

and I want to append "JNU" to every item. Desired output:

```
list1=[('car', 'JNU'), ('bike', 'JNU'), ('mango', 'JNU')]
```

I'm unable to get that result.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [13]: list1 = ['car', 'bike', 'mango'] 

In [14]: list1 = [(el, 'JNU') for el in list1]

In [15]: list1
Out[15]: [('car', 'JNU'), ('bike', 'JNU'), ('mango', 'JNU')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip()` and `itertools.repeat()`:

```
import itertools

list1 = zip(list1, itertools.repeat('JNU'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list1 = ['car','bike','mango'] 
>>> zip(list1, itertools.repeat('JNU'))
[('car', 'JNU'), ('bike', 'JNU'), ('mango', 'JNU')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation...

```
list1 = ['car', 'bike', 'mango'] 
from itertools import product

list2 = list(product(list1, ['JNU']))
```